# Why is this map not surjective at the origin?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

$f:\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$f(x) = |x|^2$

Then the derivative map is $df_{x}(v)=2\sum_{i}{x^iv^i}$ is surjective except at 0.

Is it because at 0 df only goes to 0, and doesn't cover the whole tangent space of R?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, if you plug in ${\vec x}=\vec 0$, i.e. $x^i=0$ for all $i$, then you find $df_{\vec 0}({\vec  v})$ is the sum over a bunch of zeros. So it's the constant function which evaluates to $0$ no matter what $\vec v$ is.

Comment: The OP knows $df_0 \equiv 0$.  They are asking why $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: @Strants: It's not clear, but I interpreted the OP as "this is a line I read somewhere" ... "why is it so?". In any case, I guess he knows that the codomain isn't just $\{0\}$, so pointing out that the function is constant should tell that it's not surjective.

Comment: Rereading, I think you are right.  My apologies.

Comment: Thanks everyone. And yes, I read it in a book. Interesting and funny to me, that you thought I am 'he' hehe

Answer (score 2):

A map $\varphi\colon A\to B$ is surjective, if every $b\in B$ has a preimage under $\varphi$, which is an element $a\in A$ such that $\varphi(a)=b$. Since $\mathrm df_0\colon\mathbb R^{n+1}\to\mathbb R$ maps every $v\in\mathbb R^{n+1}$ to $0\in \mathbb R$, it is not surjective. For example $1\in\mathbb R$ has no preimage under $\mathrm df_0$.